# Android command line sdkmanager tool not finding licenses for new packages

Tags: android, gradle, android-sdk-manager, pocketsphinx-android

I have downloaded and unzipped the linux command line sdk and have downloaded the Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 and Android SDK Platform 25 components as required by the Gradle build I am trying to run.  When I try and accept the new associated licenses with `./sdkmanager --licenses`, the sdkmanager says they're all up-to-date, however, when I try and run gradle build on the android library I'm trying to build (found here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android), I get:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'pocketsphinx-android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2, Android SDK Platform 25].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

So sdkmanager thinks all licenses are accepted and Gradle disagrees.  Who is right and how do I get past this error?  I'm working on the Windows 10 linux subsystem so I don't have access to a UI to use Android studio or anything like that.

Comment: Windows is your big mistake here.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Sure, but I'm using the linux subsystem though, shouldn't that suffice?  I've already fixed the issue in this ticket (will update soon) and several others following; I am stuck on a linker issue at the moment. In general, it seems like I'm having to make a lot of changes to the gradle.build and default file placements to get this thing to proceed.  Do you know if the current build docs and code bases are stable and successfully build on a pure linux platform?  If so, I'll drop the current windows-linux Frankenstein I'm using now and create a linux partition.

Comment: No, docs are not complete of course, but on Windows you'll have much more problems.